# Finding the minimum volume of a Tetrahedron.

Tags: calculus, solid-geometry

Suppose you have the surface $\xi$ defined in $\mathbb{R}^3$ by the equation:
$$ \xi :\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} + \frac{z^2}{c^2} = 1 $$
For $ x \geq 0$ , $ y \geq 0$ and $ z \geq 0$. Now take any point $P \in \xi$ and consider the tangent plane ($\pi_t)$ to $\xi$ at $P$. Calculate the minimum volume of the region determined by the $xy$, $yz$, $xz$ planes and $\pi_t$.

[image: Ellipsoid and tetrahedron.]

Comment: What have you already tried? Try editing your question to show your attempts and thoughts

Comment: This looks like a problem you have collected from / inspired by some source. According to recent discussions in Meta, we are looking forward to including sources for all applicable questions. Can you provide the source by editing the question?Refer-https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29290/is-it-a-good-idea-to-include-source-from-where-a-question-is-taken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume for the moment $a=b=c=1$. The surface $\xi$ then is the unit sphere $S^2$.  A typical point ${\bf n}$ of $S^2$ in the first octant then has coordinates $(n_1,n_2,n_3)$ with $n_i>0$ and $\sum_i n_i^2=1$. Furthermore the tangent plane to $S^2$ at ${\bf n}$ is given by the equation ${\bf n}\cdot{\bf x}=1$, i.e., $n_1x_1+n_2x_2+n_3x_3=1$. Intersecting this plane with the three coordinate axes gives the  points $\bigl({1\over n_1},0,0\bigr)$, $\bigl(0,{1\over n_2},0\bigr)$, $\bigl(0,0,{1\over n_3}\bigr)$. It follows that the simplex $S$ in question has volume
$${\rm vol}(S)={1\over 6 n_1n_2n_3}\ .$$
This volume is minimal when its reciprocal is maximal. By the AMG inequality
$$\root3\of {n_1^2 n_2^2n_3^2}\leq{1\over3}(n_1^2+n_2^2+n_3^2)={1\over3}\ ,$$
with equality iff $n_i=3^{-1/2}$ for all $i\in[3]$. It follows that
$${\rm vol}(S)\geq{1\over6} 3^{3/2}={\sqrt{3}\over2}\ .$$
In the case of arbitrary $a$, $b$, $c>0$ we therefore have
$${\rm vol}(S)\geq{\sqrt{3}\over2}abc\ ,$$
by standard geometric principles.

Answer (score 0):

Calling

$$
\begin{cases}
p_0 = (x_0,y_0,z_0)\\
p_1 = (x_1,y_1,z_1)\\
\Lambda = \mbox{diag}[\frac{1}{a^2},\frac{1}{b^2},\frac{1}{c^2}]\\
\vec n_0 = 2\Lambda\cdot p_0\\
f(p_1^*) = \frac 16 x_1^* y_1^* z_1^*\\
x_1^* = \frac{a^2}{x_0}\\
y_1^* = \frac{b^2}{y_0}\\
z_1^* = \frac{c^2}{z_0}\\
C(p_0) = p_0\cdot\Lambda\cdot p_0-1
\end{cases}
$$

Here $(x_1^*, y_1^*,z_1^*)$ are the intersections of the plane $(p_1-p_0)\cdot \vec n_0$ with the axis $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ so the problem can be stated as

$$
\min f(p_1^*)\ \ \mbox{s.t.}\ \ (p_1-p_0)\cdot \vec n_0 = 0, \ C(p_0) = 0
$$

The Lagrangian is

$$
L(p_0,p_1,\lambda,\mu) = f(p_1^*)+\lambda(p_1-p_0)\cdot \vec n_0+\mu (C(p_0)-1)
$$

and the stationary points are determined by solving

$$
\nabla L = 0
$$

or

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 \frac{2 \mu  x_0+\lambda  (x_1-2 x_0)}{a^2}-\frac{a^2 b^2 c^2}{6 x_0^2 y_0 z_0} &=&0\\
 \frac{2 \mu  y_0+\lambda  (y_1-2 y_0)}{b^2}-\frac{a^2 b^2 c^2}{6 x_0 y_0^2 z_0} &=&0\\
 \frac{2 \mu  z_0+\lambda  (z_1-2 z_0)}{c^2}-\frac{a^2 b^2 c^2}{6 x_0 y_0 z_0^2} &=&0\\
 \frac{\lambda  x_0}{a}&=&0 \\
 \frac{\lambda  y_0}{b}&=&0 \\
 \frac{\lambda  z_0}{c}&=&0 \\
 \frac{x_0 (x_1-x_0)}{a^2}+\frac{y_0 (y_1-y_0)}{b^2}+\frac{z_0 (z_1-z_0)}{c^2}&=&0 \\
 \frac{x_0^2}{a^2}+\frac{y_0^2}{b^2}+\frac{z_0^2}{c^2}&=&1 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

giving

$$
\begin{array}{cccc}
x_0&y_0&z_0& f(p_1^*)\\
\frac{a}{\sqrt{3}}&\frac{b}{\sqrt{3}}&\frac{c}{\sqrt{3}}&\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{3} a b c
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider a point $P(x_0,y_0,z_0)\in \Bbb R_{>0}^3$ on the given ellipsoid $(E)$ with equation
$$
\frac {x^2}{a^2} +
\frac {y^2}{b^2} +
\frac {z^2}{c^2} 
=1\ .
$$
Then the plane tangent in $P$ to $(E)$ is given by the linear part of the Taylor polynomial around $(x_0,y_o,z_0)$ of first order of the polynomial of second degree in the above equation, equated to zero.
To isolate this polynomial of degree one, write
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\frac {x^2}{a^2} +
\frac {y^2}{b^2} +
\frac {z^2}{c^2} 
-1
\\
&\qquad=
\frac 1{a^2} ((x-x_0)+x_0)^2+
\frac 1{b^2} ((y-y_0)+y_0)^2+
\frac 1{c^2} ((z-z_0)+z_0)^2
-1
\\
&\qquad=
\underbrace{
\left(
\frac 1{a^2} x_0^2+
\frac 1{b^2} y_0^2+
\frac 1{c^2} z_0^2
-1
\right)}_{=0}
\\
&\qquad\qquad+
\frac 2{a^2} x_0(x-x_0)+
\frac 2{b^2} y_0(y-y_0)+
\frac 2{c^2} z_0(z-z_0)
\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad+
\text{higher order terms}
\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad
\text{  containing factors $(x-x_0)^2$, and $(y-y_0)^2$, and $(z-z_0)^2$ .}
\end{aligned}
$$
So the equation of the tangent plane in $P$ to $(E)$ is (given by "dedoubling"):
$$
\frac 1{a^2} x_0(x-x_0)+
\frac 1{b^2} y_0(y-y_0)+
\frac 1{c^2} z_0(z-z_0)=0\ .
$$
Simpler maybe:
$$
\frac 1{a^2} x_0x+
\frac 1{b^2} y_0y+
\frac 1{c^2} z_0z
=1\ .
$$
This plane hits the $Ox$ axis in the point with $y=z=0$ and $x=a^2/x_0$.
Similar formulas for the intersections with the other axes.

So we have to minimize the volume:
$$
V =\frac 16\frac{a^2\;b^2\;c^2}{x_0\;y_0\;z_0}\ .
$$
For this we have to maximize the product $x_0y_0z_0$. The inequality between the arithmetic and geometric mean solves the problem.
$$
1 =
\frac {x_0^2}{a^2} +
\frac {y_0^2}{b^2} +
\frac {z_0^2}{c^2}
\ge 3\left(\frac {x_0^2y_0^2z_0^2}{a^2b^2c^2}\right)^{1/3}
=
3\left(\frac {x_0y_0z_0}{abc}\right)^{2/3}\ ,
$$
so
$$
x_0y_0z_0\le 3^{-3/2}abc\ .
$$
The quality holds for the point $P^*\left(\frac a{\sqrt 3},\frac b{\sqrt 3},\frac c{\sqrt 3}\right)$. We get the minimal volume:
$$
V^* =
\frac 16\frac{a^2b^2c^2}{3^{-3/2}abc}=
\frac {\sqrt 3}2\; abc\ .
$$

Comment: see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2340059/minimun-volume-of-a-tetrahedron-bounded-by-an-ellipsoid-and-tangent-plane

Comment: All people assume that $a=b=c=1$, which is ok mathematically, but it is not always ok didactically, my oppinion. The problems are, from the point of view of a solver with less skills in understanding the way the volume is changing and tangent planes are conserved via the transformation of the space given by the diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $a,b,c$. Also, in Olympiad condition, one looses the points. I do not need to assume $a=b=c=1$, the difference is not in essence, just in typing. I often answer, and soon see a duplicate situation. Here for 1 day was no duplication information.